# ARRAYFORMULA most recent value per item

Tags: google-sheets

I have data like this:

| prof | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 | date5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | date1 | date2 |  |  |  |
| prof1 | tarif1 | tarif2 |  |  |  |
|  | date1 |  |  |  |  |
| prof2 | tarif3 |  |  |  |  |
|  | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 | date5 |
| prof3 | tarif4 | tarif5 | tarif6 | tarif7 | tarif8 |

How can I get this answer with one arrayformula (most recent tariff per prof)

| prof | tarif |
| --- | --- |
| prof1 | tarif2 |
| prof2 | tarif3 |
| prof3 | tarif8 |

I tried to resolve that problem by 2 steps :

to get the last column

```
=query(query(arrayformula(split(flatten(A1:A&"~"&B1:F&"~"&column(B1:F1)),"~",1,0)),"where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null"),"select Col1,max(Col3) group by Col1 label max(Col3) ''")
```

then to retrieve the value

```
=offset($A$1,match(H1,A:A,0)-1,I1-1)
```

[image]

**Is there a solution to do within one single arrayformula?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=INDEX(regexextract(trim(transpose(query(transpose(filter(A:F, len(A:A))),,9^9))), "^(.*?)\s.*?([^\s]+$)"))
```

[image]

If there are spaces in the values in the range A:F you'll have to replace those with another character (and do another substitute to add those spaces back in).